# MySQL search for the string "space" does not return a result

Tags: mysql, space

I have a table with a string column `name`. It contains values, several of them contain the string "space", e.g. Spaceship, Myspace. When I run this query I get no result:

```
SELECT * FROM izz_services WHERE `name` LIKE "%space%";
```

Neither does this query return any row:

```
SELECT * FROM izz_services WHERE `name` LIKE "%spac%";
```

Actually, no combination with an 's' at the beginning does.

But this one does:

```
SELECT * FROM izz_services WHERE `name` LIKE "%pace%";
```

Why is that? How can I search for the string "space" ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What rows does the third query return?

Comment: You might be using a case-sensitive collation, so "space" does not match "Space". The second example "Myspace" should be matched even if your collation is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. It actually was the case sensitivity. The on entry is actually "MySpace". I didn't know that the collation influences that and alwasy thought that LIKE is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "string" instant of 'string'

SELECT * FROM izz_services WHERE `name` LIKE '%space%';

This should work.

Comment: This makes no difference if you use MySQL default `sql_mode`. Double-quotes and single-quotes both delimit strings.